# Why won't this simple javascript code run?

Tags: javascript, html

My html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
...
<img src="images/ham.svg" alt="Toggle Menu" class="menu" id="menu_img">
...
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

And my javascript file looks like this:

```
alert('1');

var menu = document.getElementById('menu_img'));
```

Like this, nothing happens. When I remove the second line in the script, i get the alert, so I assume that the getting of the element doesn't work properly. But, I have n clue why not. I'm new to javascript so sorry if this is very simple. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Typo - 2 `) `s.

Comment: That's because you have a syntax error which is caused by the additional closing bracket in your second line. The correct syntax is `document.getElementById('menu_img');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple syntax error. You have one too many parenthesis at the end of the line:

```
var menu = document.getElementById('menu_img'));
```

Corrected:

```
var menu = document.getElementById('menu_img');
```